# Getting file size in Python?

Tags: python, file, size

Is there a built-in function for getting the size of a file object in bytes? I see some people do something like this:

```
def getSize(fileobject):
    fileobject.seek(0,2) # move the cursor to the end of the file
    size = fileobject.tell()
    return size

file = open('myfile.bin', 'rb')
print getSize(file)
```

But from my experience with Python, it has a lot of helper functions so I'm guessing maybe there is one built-in.

Comment: `Path('./doc.txt').stat().st_size`

Answer (score 979):

Use [`os.path.getsize(path)`](https://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.getsize) which will

> Return the size, in bytes, of *path*. Raise [`OSError`](https://docs.python.org/library/exceptions.html#OSError) if the file does not exist or is inaccessible.

```
import os
os.path.getsize('C:\\Python27\\Lib\\genericpath.py')
```

Or use [`os.stat(path).st_size`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.stat)

```
import os
os.stat('C:\\Python27\\Lib\\genericpath.py').st_size
```

Or use [`Path(path).stat().st_size`](https://docs.python.org/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.stat) (Python 3.4+)

```
from pathlib import Path
Path('C:\\Python27\\Lib\\genericpath.py').stat().st_size
```

Comment: Thanks you all. I don't know if you can reply to all posts at once, so I'll just rply to the last answerer. I can't seem to get it to work. `  File "C:\\python\lib\genericpath.py", line 49, in getsize
    return os.stat(filename).st_size
TypeError: stat() argument 1 must be encoded string without NULL bytes, not str`

Comment: Think you need "C:\\python\\lib\\genericpath.py" - e.g. os.path.getsize('C:\\Python27\\Lib\\genericpath.py') or 
os.stat('C:\\Python27\\Lib\\genericpath.py').st_size

Comment: @696, Python will let you have NULL bytes it strings, but it doesn't make sense to pass those into getsize because the filename can't have NULL bytes in it

Comment: I ran both with `%timeit` on all the files in a given directory and found `os.stat` to be marginally faster (~6%).

Comment: @16num Which is just logical because `os.path.getsize()` does nothing else than calling `os.stat().st_size`.

Answer (score 253):

```
os.path.getsize(path)
```

Return the size, in bytes, of path. Raise os.error if the file does not exist or is inaccessible.

Comment: Just as a note for someone curious, getsize() behind the scenes does os.stat(path).st_size, which was the other approach explained here.

Answer (score 98):

You may use `os.stat()` function, which is a wrapper of system call `stat()`:

```
import os

def getSize(filename):
    st = os.stat(filename)
    return st.st_size
```

Comment: returns it in kb right?

Comment: No, it's in Bytes.

Answer (score 27):

Try

```
os.path.getsize(filename)
```

It should return the size of a file, reported by os.stat().

Answer (score 16):

You can use `os.stat(path)` call

http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.stat