# File size is zero

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a simple script that looks at various files and manipulates them depending on file size, but I've tried both :

```
os.stat(path + fname).st_size
```

and

```
os.path.getsize(path + fname)
```

but both return a result of '0'.  I'm running Kubuntu but the file system is NTFS formatted, could this be the problem, or does anyone have any reason why this may be happening?

** EDIT **

Somehow all my files have been emptied of all their data.  Please ignore this, the filesize is being reported correct.

Comment: It's probably related to the filesystem. Try it on an ext partition to see if it works properly there.

Comment: Pardon me for asking the obvious, but does the file in question actually have non-zero size?

Comment: If you display the size of the file in the shell or using a file manager, does it show the correct size?

Comment: Appreciate everyones help - somehow all my files go zero sized and my file manager hadn't update

Comment: @Martyn: I suggest you close this question.

Comment: I am seeing the same behavior in Python 2.7.11 on OS X. I believe it is related to Apple's disk format

Answer (score 1):

Don't build filenames as if they're plain strings. Use `os.path` helper functions.  You could be missing a separator, or have double separators, or something.

Also try "validating" (or just plain inspecting) the filename, perhaps there are embedded NUL bytes that are causing confusion. See [this comment to a different question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6591931/getting-file-size-in-python#comment7776545_6591957).

Comment: That's good advise, but if the filename was the problem, wouldn't stat fail instead of returning 0?

Comment: same behaviour with `os.path.getsize(os.path.join(path, fname))`