# Why no len(file) in Python?

Tags: python

I'm not exactly new to Python, but I do still have trouble understanding what makes something "Pythonic" (and the converse).

So forgive me if this is a stupid question, but why can't I get the size of a file by doing a len(file)?

file.`__len__` is not even implemented, so it's not like it's needed for something else?  Would it be confusing/inconsistent for some reason if it was implemented to return the file size?

Comment: (1) In python interactive interpreter execute `import this`. (2) because to implement that you would need to read the file to it's end. So, you'd better ask OS to do that for you (e.g. like in [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6591931/getting-file-size-in-python))

Comment: because someone came up with  os.stat and statinfo.st_size

Answer (score 25, accepted):

file is an iterator. To find the number of *lines* you need to read the entire file

```
sum(1 for line in file)
```

if you want the number of *bytes* in a file, use `os.stat`

eg

```
import os
os.stat(filename).st_size
```

Comment: OK, the iterator thing makes sense.  I guess to implement `__len__` for a file it would have to read the file into memory and then do a len() on the buffer.  Probably not a great idea.  So you can ask the OS, which already knows the file size, hence os.stat.  Thanks!

Answer (score 26):

Files have a broader definition, especially in Unix, than you may be thinking. What is the length of a printer, for example? Or a CDROM drive? Both are files in /dev, and sort of in Windows.

For what we normally think of as a file, what would its length be? The size of the variable? The size of the file in bytes? The latter makes more sense, but then it gets ickier. Should the size of the file's contents be listed, or its size on disk (modulus allocation unit size). The question arises again for sparse files (files that have large empty sections which take no space, but are part of the file's normally reported size, supported by some file systems like NTFS and XFS).

Of course, the answer to all of those could be, "just pick one and document what you picked." Perhaps that is exactly what should be done, but to be Pythonic, something usually must be clear-cut without having to read a lot of docs. `len(string)` is mostly obvious (one may ask if bytes or characters are the return value), `len(array)` is obvious, `len(file)` maybe not quite enough.

Comment: Worth noting that in Python 3, the strong distinction between `str` (a sequence of code points) and `bytes` (a sequence of bytes) compared to the `unicode`/`str` distinction in Python 2 makes it clearer how `__len__` should be defined for each.

Comment: Thanks, this is a great answer.  I just gave the solution to @gnibbler because he was the first to point out the technical reason why `__len__` wouldn't work well for a file.

Answer (score 9):

`file` returns an iterator, so you can't use `len()` on it.

To get the size of a file  you can use [`os.stat`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.stat):

```
>>> foo = os.stat("abc")
>>> foo.st_size
193L
```

If by size you mean number of line then try these:

```
len(open("abc").readlines())
```

or

`sum (1 for _ in open("abc"))`

Comment: For Python 3 learners, "193L" does not mean "193 lines", it used to mean something like "193 is a Large number".

Comment: I think L stood for "Long"

Answer (score 5):

> So forgive me if this is a stupid question, but why can't I get the
>   size of a file by doing a len(file)?

Charles Burns' answer makes a good point about Unix's "everything is a file" philosophy, and, although you always can use `os.fstat()` to get the 'size' for any file descriptor, with something like...

```
import os

f = open(anything)
size = os.fstat(f.fileno()).st_size
```

...it may not return anything meaningful or useful...

```
>>> os.fstat(sys.stdout.fileno()).st_size
0
>>> fd1, fd2 = os.pipe()
>>> os.fstat(fd1).st_size
0
```

I think the reason is that a Python file object, or file-like object, is supposed to represent a stream, and streams don't inherently have a length, especially if they're write-only, like `sys.stdout`.

Usually, the only thing you *can* guarantee about a Python file-like object is that it will support at least one of `read()` or `write()`, and that's about it.

Answer (score 3):

A simple way to measure the number of characters  would be:

```
file = open('file.bin', 'r')
# Seek to the end. (0 bytes relative to the end)
file.seek(0, 2)
length = file.tell()
```

Comment: Possibly undefined behavior for binary files: https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/c/FIO19-C.+Do+not+use+fseek%28%29+and+ftell%28%29+to+compute+the+size+of+a+regular+file

Answer (score 2):

I would say because finding the length depends on OS specific functionality. You can find the length of a file with this code:

`import os
os.path.getsize('C:\\file.txt')`

You could also read the entire file into a string and find the length of the string. However you would want to be sure that the file is not of a huge size that will eat up all your memory.