# how to know that the given file's size is less than 10MB or not? Python

Tags: python, file, directory, size

```
import os
import subprocess

fileName = 'file.txt'

b = subprocess.check_output(['du','-sh', fileName]).split()[0].decode('utf-8')
print b
```

'''
if b is less than 10MB then continue else break
'''

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2104080/how-to-check-file-size-in-python

Comment: why not try yourself first [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6591931/getting-file-size-in-python)

Answer (score 3):

Original answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2104107/5283213

Use `os.stat`, and use the `st_size` member of the resulting object:

```
import os
statinfo = os.stat('somefile.txt')

print statinfo
(33188, 422511L, 769L, 1, 1032, 100, 926L, 1105022698,1105022732, 1105022732)

print statinfo.st_size
926L
```

> Output is in bytes.

> edit to check if `10MB` file or not

It's simple: use an `if` statement and some maths:

```
if statinfo.st_size <= 10485760: # and not 10 000 000 as 1024 * 1024 * 10
    print "size is less than 10MB"
else:
    print "greater than 10MB"
```

Comment: i want to know is that file's size is less than 10MB or not.
it will be really helpful to get the proper answer for it. :)

Comment: @SunehaBanuJ there you go, that should do it

Comment: hey thanks..
it worked :)

Comment: @SunehaBanuJ if it *did* work, then mark the answer as accepted for others to review later :)

Comment: It *was* pointed out before, and I flagged the question too, but the OP's question needed more, et al, the `if` statement.

Answer (score 2):

You could use this

```
import os
os.path.getsize('path_to_dir/file.txt')
```

or

```
os.stat('path_to_dir/file.txt').st_size
```

Meanwhile, this is a duplicate question. Next time onwards do make sure to check if a question on the same already exists.
Cheers!