# How can I check any file size with zero using if without import os in python

Tags: python-2.7, hdfs

I want to Check file size in hdfs using python but using hdfs path this os module doesn't work so how can I do this without import os 
Below is the code snippet

```
import os
hdfs_path='hdfs://user/mohitm/sagar/test1.csv'
if os.stat(hdfs_path).st_size>0:
        print("File is not empty")
else:
        print("Empty File")
```

can any one tell me how can I do this without import os
Thanks

Comment: Please look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/6591931/11314993

Comment: Why not `os`? It contains file/path related functions.

Comment: Not sure if its python2 but you can take a look at https://hdfscli.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html - especially at https://hdfscli.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#hdfs.client.Client.status to get the files lenght. Have fun.