# How to determine size of the record while uploading file to GCP

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

I am facing below error while uploading file to a GCP bucket. Few records are exceeding (10000000 bytes) allowed by GCP. I have a working Python script to upload file in GCP which uses upload blob functionality. Need to enhance this script to identify & capture records exceeding this limit.

**Error:**
google.cloud.pubsub_v1.publisher.exceptions.MessageTooLargeError: The message being published would produce too large a publish request that would exceed the maximum allowed size on the backend (10000000 bytes).

Answer (score 1):

Are these normal files that you are converting to blobs and uploading? If so you could perform a check on the size of the file using [these techniques](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6591931/getting-file-size-in-python) so something like

```
if os.path.getsize(filepath) < 10000000:
    upload(filepath)
else:
    continue
```

Edit:

Finding the size of indiviual records would be harder. [The second result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33978/find-out-how-much-memory-is-being-used-by-an-object-in-python) indicates you can find the memory size of objects, but you may want to pad your limit to avoid the error.

Alternatively you could save the record to a temporary file and then get the size of that file for a slower but more bullet proof method of finding the record size

Comment: Thanks, but this is based on file size. I want to capture the records inside the files which are exceeding that size. Should be able to upload the file with other good records.